# PHP mention script

Tags: php

I'm working on a mention script that gets an users profile link when it is being mentioned in a news article or something. I've done the mention script, but it splits the users name after it finds a space. When an user wants to mention somebody they will start their name with a @ symbol.

So my script stops after it finds a space. That means if I wanted to mention an username such as @This is. It would only pick up This.

Could anyone tell me how I can pick up usernames with spaces in? Here is my script.

```
    <?php

 $string = "I'm wanting to speak to the user @This is please.";
 $explosion = explode("@", $string);
 $count = count($explosion);

 for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++){
    $explosion2 = explode(" ", $explosion[$i]);
    $explosion2 = $explosion2[0];

    $string = str_replace("@{$explosion2}", "{$explosion2} yeah", $string);
 }

 echo $string;
?>
```

Thank you.

Comment: The problem as I see there is that you have to make diference on what spaces you whant to make part of the name and which ones not... In your example how to difference if the name is `This is` or `This is please`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no way to figure out if a username is just one word or multiple words from your example because the username has the exact same formatting as the rest of the string. There are a few ways you can fix this.

You explode on @ then read up until you reach some indicator of the end of the username. So strings would then need to be altered to have special indicators at the beginning AND END of usernames:

```
$string = "I'm wanting to speak to the user @This is@ please.";
```

This would be very convenient for you because you would only have to call explode once since the whole username would be in the array's second element.

Comment: +1 For consistency via explicit mentions. Today I may find that `@This is please` behaves like expected (mentions user `This is`), but tomorrow it may change (if user `This is please` is created in the meantime).

Answer (score 2):

What if there are two users named "This" and "This is" and you have a text: "@This is, do you think @This is being serious?"

My advice would be to disallow spaces in usernames. It can cause more trouble than it's worth in many other situations anyway (URL creation, for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a way to look up names? What I mean is, you need to be able to exclude `This is` (and even `This is please`) in order to find the user `This` (if that was the intended user).

The naïve implementation would extract the string between the `@` character *and the first character not valid in a username* (e.g., `.`). This would give the string `This is please`. You could then chop off one word at a time and see if a username matches.

This strategy, however, does not allow me to mention the user `This` in the string `"@This is not me."` if the user `This is` exists.

To overcome this, the mention should be **explicit with regard to the username**. This can be achieved via delimiters (character that can themselves not be part of the username), e.g.:

```
I'm wanting to speak to the user [This is] please.
```

See [@Jons' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6252022/php-mention-script/6252088#6252088), too.

Answer (score 0):

You have to edit this line:

```
$explosion2 = explode(" ", $explosion[$i]);
```

Other wise it will get only the first word. If you want take all the name up until a dot for example do this:

```
$explosion2 = explode(".", $explosion[$i]);
```

Comment: @joshua: then simply you can't have both.

Comment: There is a way. I just don't know it.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that the string is: `$string = "I'm wanting to speak to the user @This is please.";`
And `please` is not part of the user's name. So the script would be getting the incorrect (possibly non-existent) user.

Comment: There is a way, but as I mentioned in my reply, there's no way to make it 100% correct. And even if used, it would require additional SQL queries for each possibility. If my username is "m_i_n_g_o_s" (change underscores to spaces), the algorithm would query the DB for "m", "m_i", "m_i_n", etc. That's a wasteful thing to do, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Usually username doesn't contain spaces.

Comment: This doesn't really begin to answer the question, IMHO.

Comment: @jensgram, it does: disallow spaces in usernames. Solutions to problems aren't always what you expect them to be.

Comment: @mingos The problem, as I see it, is not the space character *per se*. It's with the non-explicit mention. I would go with explicit mentions instead, e.g. `"I'm wanting to speak to the user [This is] please."`

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to use a callback and need some means to determine if a username exists. You cannot guess from the words alone. And for simplicity I would prefer a regex callback here:

```
$str= preg_replace_callback('/@(\w+)( \w+)?( \w+)?/', 'rx_users', $str);

function rx_users($match) {
    list($asis, $one, $two, $three) = $match;

    if (user_exists($user=$one)
    or  user_exists($user="$one$two")
    or  user_exists($user="$one$two$three"))
    {
        return "<a href=user/$user>$user</a>";
    }
    else return $asis;
}
```

So it doesn't work without a `user_exists()` test. But you can of course always fallback to assuming the username is just `@$one` word per default.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the solution to this problem would be to assign a unique numerical identifier to each registered user on sign up.
Each user could then be referenced by username and/or their real name - with or without spaces between first and second names.

Strings beginning with @ would initiate a search of all users in a list which could then be selected from a drop down much like facebook or twitter.